# How do I access dynamically generated/rendered children within a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First, I've got a class component (for this example, let's call it DynamicComponent) that takes in no children, but dynamically generates HTML. Example render function for DynamicComponent:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="first" />
            <input type="text" name="last" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

In a separate/parent component (I'll call it `<Form>`), I'm looping through child elements and searching for  elements in order to register them on a form and perform validation on them. The issue here is that when it gets to the recursive part at the bottom of the function (`child.type === 'DynamicComponent'`), `child.props.children` is undefined (to be expected, since I don't pass any children as props to the DynamicComponent). How would I go about getting the dynamically rendered  fields from within this parent component that's running this `getChildInputs` function? Simplified function (it's an accumulation function being passed into `.reduce()`):

```
getChildInputs = (acc, child) => {
    // Find form elements and make note of their validation requirements
    if (
        typeof child.type === 'string' &&
        (child.type === 'input' || child.type === 'textarea')
    ) {
        acc[child.props.id] = {
            valid: true,
            touched: false,
            rules: [],
            invalidRules: [],
        };
        if (child.props.required) {
            acc[child.props.id].rules.push('required');
        }
        if (child.props.type === 'email') {
            acc[child.props.id].rules.push('email');
        }
        if (typeof child.props.match !== 'undefined') {
            acc[child.props.id].rules.push('match');
            acc[child.props.id].match = child.props.match;
        }
        if (typeof child.props.maxLength !== 'undefined') {
            acc[child.props.id].rules.push('maxLength');
            acc[child.props.id].maxLength = child.props.maxLength;
        }
    }
    // Make it a recursive search
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        React.Children.toArray(child.props.children).reduce(Form.getChildInputs, acc);
    }
    return acc;
}
```

Parent () component render function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <DynamicComponent />
            <AnotherChildComponent>
                <input type="text" name="input1" />
                <input type="text" name="input2" />
            </AnotherChildComponent>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So in this case, the getChildInputs function would reduce to an array with the `input1` and `input2` elements, but it wouldn't pickup the `first` and `last` elements. Is there a way for me to get the actual children of an element/component, not just rely on `props.children`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use ref here. Create ref in your parent component and forward it to your child. After that you can access children of child component calling ref.current.children. Here is some code example, I hope you would be able to adapt it to your particular example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.ref = createRef();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.ref.current.children)
    // would console log 
    // HTMLCollection {0: HTMLInputElement, 1: HTMLInputElement, length: 2, item: ƒ item(), namedItem: ƒ namedItem()…}
    // 0: 
    // <input type="text" name="first"></input>
    // 1: 
    // <input type="text" name="last"></input>
    // length: 2
    // item: ƒ item() {}
    // namedItem: ƒ namedItem() {}
    // <constructor>: "HTMLCollection"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Dynamic ref={this.ref}  />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>A</button>
      </div>
    );

  }

}


const Dynamic = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        <input type="text" name="first" />
        <input type="text" name="last" />
    </div>
  )
})
```